# Implicit differentiation to determine area/angle of triangle

Tags: trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

Let *O* denote the origin of the axis of co-ordinates, and let *C* denote the part of the parabola $y=x^2$ which lies in the first quadrant. A particle *P* starts at *O* and moves along *C* in such a way that its distance from the y-axis is increasing at a rate of 3 units per second. Let *Q* denote the point where the tangent to the parabola at the point *P* intersects the x-axis, and let *R* denote the foot of the perpendicular from *P* to the x-axis. 
Let $\phi$ denote the angle (in radians) subtended at the vertex *Q* of the triangle *PQR*. How fast is $\phi$ changing, when *P* is 4 units away from the y-axis?

My attempt at a solution:

We are given $\frac{dx}{dt}$ $=3$ units/second. We'll use $P(u,u^2)$. We want $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ when $u=4$.

When *P* is 4 units away from the y-axis, we have $P(4,16)$ and $R(4,0)$. I found the x-intercept of *Q* by writing the following equations:

$$y-u^2=2u(x-u)$$

$$0-16=2(4)(x-4)\Rightarrow x=2$$

So *Q* lies on $(2,0)$. We now have a triangle with side lengths $||PQ||=\sqrt{20}, ||PR||=4, ||QR||=2$.

To find $\phi$:
$$tan(\phi)=\frac{||PR||}{||QR||}=\frac{16}{2}=8\Rightarrow\frac{d\phi}{dx}=arctan(8)$$
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}=arctan(8)\cdot3$$

Am I even approaching this correctly? I'm really not sure if that will work or if I should be using $||PQ||$. We were also supposed to find the area of the triangle at this instant and I found it to be 48, but for some reason I'm unsure about the angle part and if this method will still give me the correct value over a change in time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got something wrong, $\phi =\arctan (8)$ but not $\frac{d\phi}{dx}

Note that tangent of the angle is simply 
$\tan \phi=\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ because the slope of the line $PQ$ is the same as the derivative of the curve at that point. Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$

$$\sec^2 \phi \frac{d\phi}{dx}=2$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=2\cos^2 \phi \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: Ah, I see now. Definitely felt like I was missing something. Thanks!

Comment: @Kathryn You're welcome :)

Comment: Actually I'm still confused... I guess I understand why that would be the change in $\phi$, but if I'm actually trying to solve for this value how do I know what the angle is in the first place? Just use the values for when x=4? I'm getting 0.0923 radians and that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Kathryn That is correct, because the angle as $x$ tends to infinity is $\pi/2$ radian. And the angle at $x=4$ is already about $82°$, so the increase will be slow